# Most popular choices based on the concern of ingredients

Tags: food-identification

For example I can name it these choices:

`gluten free, vegan, vegetarian, organic` etc.,

Is there any other style options?

Comment: Too many to list, many overlapping, some mutually exclusive. What's your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the concern of ingredients:

Gluten free, Keto, Vegan, Vegetarian, Non-vegeterian, pescatarian, Eggeterian etc.

Based on types of cuisine:

Continental, Italian, Thai, Mexican, Burmese, Lebanese etc.

Based on cooking techniques:

Barbeque, Baked treats, Let's steam, Straight from grill, Stir fries etc

Based on the dishes:

Salad station, wrap & rolls, one pot meals, puddings, munchies etc.

Comment: Then there's the see-food diet (my favourite).

Comment: @Mick yes....Pescatarian is all about sea food diet

Comment: it was a joke (I see food and eat it).